# Access Unity values from Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine

I do Unity Swift integration follow this example https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5

After doing that, how can I access a unity value (for example a score value) into my Swift code?

I can see the value in the Xcode console but I don't know how to access the value into my swift project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Option 1) Save in `UserDefaults`

Option 2) Create iOS plugin and can pass values to a native project.

Let me know if you want to go with the second option I will share more details on that.